# Rails: How to return only one attribute from a Model.all.to_a list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

This seems like it should be really simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out or find the proper syntax anywhere. If I have a Model with an Name, how do I print a list of every Name in the database? I've tried every variation of this I can think of:

```
Model.names.all.to_a
```

but I always recieve an error saying that "names" is not a recognized method for the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
Model.all.map(&:name)
```

which is a shortcut to

```
Model.all.map { |model| model.name }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an optimized way to do the same thing:

```
Model.pluck(:name)
```